# Minimizing and maximizing the sum of the diagonals of a pentagon with unit sides

Tags: geometry

Consider quadrangle $ABCD$ such that $|AB| = |BC| = |CD| = |DA| = 1$.
It is known that the minimum of $|AC| + |BD|$ is $2$, and the maximum is $2\sqrt{2}$.

> Now, consider pentagon $ABCDE$ such that $|AB| = |BC| = |CD| = |DE| = |EA| = 1$. What are the minimum and maximum of $|AC|+|CE|+|EB|+|BD|+|DA|$?

Comment: I suspect the maximum is reached for a regular pentagon (sum of diagonals $\approx 8.09$) and the minimum for the degenerate case where $ABC$ is an equilateral triangle, $D=A$ and $E=C$ (sum of diagonals $= 3$). But have no proof at the moment.